# Pygame Tetris Game Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I can't figure out how to fix the pygame problems here. I'm pretty sure it's with the pygame.keydown function, but I'm not positive. Everytime I run the program, it will open a window, but it won't start the game. Thanks in advance for your help!

```py
import pygame
import random

"""
10 x 20 square grid
shapes: S, Z, I, O, J, L, T
represented in order by 0 - 6
"""

pygame.font.init()

# GLOBALS VARS
s_width = 800
s_height = 700
play_width = 300  # meaning 300 // 10 = 30 width per block
play_height = 600  # meaning 600 // 20 = 20 height per blo ck
block_size = 30

top_left_x = (s_width - play_width) // 2
top_left_y = s_height - play_height

# SHAPE FORMATS

S = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '..00.',
      '.00..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '...0.',
      '.....']]

Z = [['.....',
    '.....',
    '.00..',
    '..00.',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '..0..',
    '.00..',
    '.0...',
    '.....']]

I = [['..0..',
    '..0..',
    '..0..',
    '..0..',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '0000.',
    '.....',
    '.....',
    '.....']]

O = [['.....',
    '.....',
    '.00..',
    '.00..',
    '.....']]

J = [['.....',
    '.0...',
    '.000.',
    '.....',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '..00.',
    '..0..',
    '..0..',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '.....',
    '.000.',
    '...0.',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '..0..',
    '..0..',
    '.00..',
    '.....']]

L = [['.....',
    '...0.',
    '.000.',
    '.....',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '..0..',
    '..0..',
    '..00.',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '.....',
    '.000.',
    '.0...',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '.00..',
    '..0..',
    '..0..',
    '.....']]

T = [['.....',
    '..0..',
    '.000.',
    '.....',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '..0..',
    '..00.',
    '..0..',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '.....',
    '.000.',
    '..0..',
    '.....'],
    ['.....',
    '..0..',
    '.00..',
    '..0..',
    '.....']]

shapes = [S, Z, I, O, J, L, T]
shape_colors = [(0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (255, 165, 0), (0, 0, 255), (128, 0, 128)]
# index 0 - 6 represent shape


class Piece(object):
    rows = 20  # y
    columns = 10  # x

    def __init__(self, column, row, shape):
        self.x = column
        self.y = row
        self.shape = shape
        self.color = shape_colors[shapes.index(shape)]
        self.rotation = 0  # number from 0-3


def create_grid(locked_positions={}):
    grid = [[(0, 0, 0) for x in range(10)] for x in range(20)]

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if (j, i) in locked_positions:
                c = locked_positions[(j, i)]
                grid[i][j] = c
    return grid


def convert_shape_format(shape):
    positions = []
    format = shape.shape[shape.rotation % len(shape.shape)]

    for i, line in enumerate(format):
        row = list(line)
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == '0':
                positions.append((shape.x + j, shape.y + i))


    for i, pos in enumerate(positions):
        positions[i] = (pos[0] - 2, pos[1] - 4)

    return positions


def valid_space(shape, grid):
    accepted_positions = [[(j, i) for j in range(10) if grid[i][j] == (0, 0, 0)] for i in range(20)]
    accepted_positions = [j for sub in accepted_positions for j in sub]
    formatted = convert_shape_format(shape)

    for pos in formatted:
        if pos not in accepted_positions:
            if pos[1] > -1:
                return False

    return True


def check_lost(positions):
    for pos in positions:
        x, y = pos
        if y < 1:
            return True
    return False


def get_shape():
    global shapes, shape_colors

    return Piece(5, 0, random.choice(shapes))


def draw_text_middle(text, size, color, surface):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', size, bold=True)
    label = font.render(text, 1, color)

    surface.blit(label, (top_left_x + play_width / 2 - (label.get_width() / 2), top_left_y + play_height / 2 - label.get_height() / 2))


def draw_grid(surface, row, col):
    sx = top_left_x
    sy = top_left_y
    for i in range(row):
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (128, 128, 128), (sx, sy + i * 30), (sx + play_width, sy + i * 30))  # horizontal lines
        for j in range(col):
            pygame.draw.line(surface, (128, 128, 128), (sx + j * 30, sy), (sx + j * 30, sy + play_height))  # vertical lines


def clear_rows(grid, locked):
    # need to see if row is clear the shift every other row above down one

    inc = 0
    for i in range(len(grid) - 1, -1, -1):
        row = grid[i]
        if (0, 0, 0) not in row:
            inc += 1
            # add positions to remove from locked
            ind = i
            for j in range(len(row)):
                try:
                    del locked[(j, i)]
                except:
                    continue
    if inc > 0:
        for key in sorted(list(locked), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
            x, y = key
            if y < ind:
                newKey = (x, y + inc)
                locked[newKey] = locked.pop(key)


def draw_next_shape(shape, surface):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
    label = font.render('Next Shape', 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x + play_width + 50
    sy = top_left_y + play_height / 2 - 100
    format = shape.shape[shape.rotation % len(shape.shape)]

    for i, line in enumerate(format):
        row = list(line)
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == '0':
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, shape.color, (sx + j * 30, sy + i * 30, 30, 30), 0)

    surface.blit(label, (sx + 10, sy - 30))


def draw_window(surface):
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Tetris Title
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
    label = font.render('TETRIS', 1, (255,255,255))

    surface.blit(label, (top_left_x + play_width / 2 - (label.get_width() / 2), 30))

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, grid[i][j], (top_left_x + j * 30, top_left_y + i * 30, 30, 30), 0)

    # draw grid and border
    draw_grid(surface, 20, 10)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (top_left_x, top_left_y, play_width, play_height), 5)
    # pygame.display.update()


def main():
    global grid

    locked_positions = {}  # (x,y):(255,0,0)
    grid = create_grid(locked_positions)

    change_piece = False
    run = True
    current_piece = get_shape()
    next_piece = get_shape()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fall_time = 0

    while run:
        fall_speed = 0.27

        grid = create_grid(locked_positions)
        fall_time += clock.get_rawtime()
        clock.tick()

        # PIECE FALLING CODE
        if fall_time / 1000 >= fall_speed:
            fall_time = 0
            current_piece.y += 1
            if not (valid_space(current_piece, grid)) and current_piece.y > 0:
                current_piece.y -= 1
                change_piece = True

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    current_piece.x -= 1
                    if not valid_space(current_piece, grid):
                        current_piece.x += 1

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    current_piece.x += 1
                    if not valid_space(current_piece, grid):
                        current_piece.x -= 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    # rotate shape
                    current_piece.rotation = current_piece.rotation + 1 % len(current_piece.shape)
                    if not valid_space(current_piece, grid):
                        current_piece.rotation = current_piece.rotation - 1 % len(current_piece.shape)

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    # move shape down
                    current_piece.y += 1
                    if not valid_space(current_piece, grid):
                        current_piece.y -= 1

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    while valid_space(current_piece, grid):
                        current_piece.y += 1
                    current_piece.y -= 1
                    print(convert_shape_format(current_piece)) # todo fix

    shape_pos = convert_shape_format(current_piece)

    # add piece to the grid for drawing
    for i in range(len(shape_pos)):
        x, y = shape_pos[i]
        if y > -1:
            grid[y][x] = current_piece.color

    # IF PIECE HIT GROUND
    if change_piece:
        for pos in shape_pos:
            p = (pos[0], pos[1])
            locked_positions[p] = current_piece.color
        current_piece = next_piece
        next_piece = get_shape()
        change_piece = False

        # call four times to check for multiple clear rows
        clear_rows(grid, locked_positions)

    draw_window(win)
    draw_next_shape(next_piece, win)
    pygame.display.update()

    # Check if user lost
    if check_lost(locked_positions):
        run = False


    draw_text_middle("You Lost", 40, (255, 255, 255), win)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(2000)


def main_menu():
    run = True
    while run:
        win.fill((0, 0, 0))
        draw_text_middle('Press any key to begin.', 60, (255, 255, 255), win)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                main()
                pygame.quit()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((s_width, s_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tetris')

main_menu()  # start game
```

I'm new to python and pygame so I'm just trying to play around and follow tutorials online. Thanks so much!

Comment: Try making an MVCE that reduces the scope of the question down the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. Often in doing that you'll find the root of the issue, and if not, come back and post the minimal example with questions. As you have it, you're not going to find too many takers where the amount of code is so large. Like finding a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is basically a request for debugging your code. Python has a builtin function `print` that allows to write to console, which is useful for debugging.

I've inserted line:

```py
def main_menu():
    [..]
           if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               main()
               print("started")  # this is a new line
               pygame.quit()
```

When I pressed any key, I got this output:

```
python test.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.10.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
started
```

So in fact this is not a problem with events, so if not in events loop, it has to be in `main()` function.

And then, look what I've found:

```py
def main():
    [...]
    while run:
        [...]
    shape_pos = convert_shape_format(current_piece)

    # add piece to the grid for drawing
    for i in range(len(shape_pos)):
        x, y = shape_pos[i]
        if y > -1:
            grid[y][x] = current_piece.color

    # IF PIECE HIT GROUND
    if change_piece:
        for pos in shape_pos:
            p = (pos[0], pos[1])
            locked_positions[p] = current_piece.color
        current_piece = next_piece
        next_piece = get_shape()
        change_piece = False

        # call four times to check for multiple clear rows
        clear_rows(grid, locked_positions)

    draw_window(win)
    draw_next_shape(next_piece, win)
    pygame.display.update()

    # Check if user lost
    if check_lost(locked_positions):
        run = False


    draw_text_middle("You Lost", 40, (255, 255, 255), win)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(2000)
```

So where is the problem? Seems like a valid code. It is this part to be exact:

```py
def main():
    [...]
    while run:
        [...]
    shape_pos = convert_shape_format(current_piece)
    [...]
```

You have game and drawing logic outside the game loop, so it will be executed only once after the game ends. Solution is to move that code to the `while run:` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the problem and taught me how to identify it in the future. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation error.
This block of text should be indented one more time to be in the while loop in main.

```
        shape_pos = convert_shape_format(current_piece)

        # add piece to the grid for drawing
        for i in range(len(shape_pos)):
            x, y = shape_pos[i]
            if y > -1:
                grid[y][x] = current_piece.color

        # IF PIECE HIT GROUND
        if change_piece:
            for pos in shape_pos:
                p = (pos[0], pos[1])
                locked_positions[p] = current_piece.color
            current_piece = next_piece
            next_piece = get_shape()
            change_piece = False

            # call four times to check for multiple clear rows
            clear_rows(grid, locked_positions)

        draw_window(win)
        draw_next_shape(next_piece, win)
        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if user lost
        if check_lost(locked_positions):
            run = False
```